# How can I apply any function?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if a list of words are in each row of a CSV file, each row represent and article in the 'Art' column.

I tried to use any function to represent if at least of one word appear in it.
A made a column called 'Class' that prints True/False.

```
text['Class'] = text['Art'].apply(lambda a: any([word for word in a if word in keys]))
```

But when I applied, it doesn't work.

```
|------|------|
|Art_ 1| False|
|------|------|
|Art_2 | False|
|------|------|
|Art_3 | False|
|------|------|
|Art_4 | False|
|------|------|
```

The output would be:

```
|------|------|
|Art_ 1| True |
|------|------|
|Art_2 | False|
|------|------|
|Art_3 | True |
|------|------|
|Art_4 | True |
|------|------|
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `str.contains`

```
text['Class']=text['Art'].str.contains('|'.join(keys))
```

Update

```
text['Class2']=text['Art'].str.split(' ').isin(keys).mean(axis=1)>0.5
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. If I need to add a filter? For example if at least of the 50% of the words are True append True to the 'Class' column

Comment: @ChachoFuva so you mean , you have multiple words in each cell ?

Comment: I have an input list of words and a csv file with articles (in each row). I would like to assign True in 'Class' column if at least of the 50% of the total of words from the inputs were True

Comment: I do, but it does not work, prints: built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x0000016A0484C170
If I stemming 'Arts' column. What could I do?